# Proof that truncation of a regular language is regular

Tags: regular-languages

Let $L_1$ be a regular language and $L_2$ any language.  I want to prove that the language of $L_1$ truncated by $L_2$ is a regular language, i.e.

$$\{w| wx\in L_1 \text{ and } x\in  L_2\}$$

is regular.

To prove that something is regular it is enough to prove that it is described by a regular expression.  We know that $L_1$ is described by a regular expression, but regular expressions don't handle "differences" in any obvious way.

We could imagine the DFA which accepts exactly the strings of $L_1$.  But to truncate the strings of $L_2$ we would need some way of recognizing the portions of the tail of the word which are in $L_2$ and there may be no DFA which does this.  Likewise for any recognizing DFA.

In general it's hard to imagine having "any language" interact with a regular language to produce a regular language.  The "any language" isn't constrained by any of the tools that seem relevant to regular languages, like NFAs and regular expressions.

Comment: The described language is not clear to me, do you mean $\{wx \mid ...\}$?

Comment: @Watercrystal Nope, it is the language of all words which are made from $L_1$-prefixes followed by a suffix that is a word in $L_2$.

Comment: The term to search for is [**right quotient**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_of_a_formal_language). For example, [questions and answers about regular languages and right quotient](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=regular+right+quotient).